# How to correctly use Bootstrap table data-url property?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am trying to figure out how to use the data-url property of Bootstrap table
Here is my code. I have added all the necessary CSS/JS files and referenced a correct JSON form file in the the data-url property but still it ain't showing any results. What am I missing here ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Required CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.css">

</head>

<body>

<table class ="table table-hover" id ="table" data-toggle="table" data-url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/master/json/data1.json">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>

<!-- Required js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script>
    $(table).bootstrapTable('refresh', {
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/master/json/data1.json'
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the network tab in your browser debugger. Most likely you're getting a 400 error because of the Same-origin Policy. The browser can't* request content from a different domain than the one it's hosted on.

*Generally true, there are ways around this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Yes, you are very correct, but according to the example here http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/13/ ( from: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/) my jsfiddle example should also work but it isn't https://jsfiddle.net/gsz6kkzq/. It is using the data object to load fields

Comment: I made some tweaks and got it working. I removed data-toggle="table" and changed
`$("#table").bootstrapTable('refresh', {
      data: d
    }); `

to this:

`$("#table").bootstrapTable({
      data: d
    });`

https://jsfiddle.net/gsz6kkzq/1/

Comment: Yes, Thanks you. wonder why the first one doesn't work. Maybe browser issue or something. Thanks anyway.